# How can I add a sticky-header that overlays my main navigation header?

Tags: html, css, wordpress, header, sticky

`<div class="sticky-header nav-row stick">
<span class="sticky-text">
<i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
<strong>Don't wait another day. Your marketing solution is just a phone call away.</strong>
</span>
<a class="sticky-link" href="tel:561-396-9895" 561 396 9895</a>
</div>`

Here is the code I compiled, but it is not working on wordpress... How should I adjust it? Also, is it possible to do this with css?

Answer (score 2):

You need css to do it, some may even say js, but you haven't provided any css code to help come up with an answer. Try following along to this guide on w3 schools

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_sticky_header.asp

It should help solve your problems.

*for a quick fix try adding the code below to your sticky-header class or create a new class or id for it*

```
position: fixed;
top: 0;
left: 0;
z-index: 1000;
```

make sure your main navigation header has a z-index property less than 1000

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could use the css z-index :

```css
    .stickyHeader {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    background-color: lightgreen;
    height: 50px;
    }
    
    header {
    position: fixed;
    height: 30%;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: gray;
    }
```

```html
<header>Header</header>

    <div class='stickyHeader'>
    <p>Example (under this is the header)</p>
    </div>


    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
```

does this help?